# angular 5 matsnackbar change action button color

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I'm using MatSnackBar for my angular 5 project, and I cannot seem to change the color of the 'action' button.

I've injected the snack bar to my HttpInterceptor:

```
    this.snackBar.open('Invalid Login', 'Ok', {
                    duration: 2000,
                    panelClass: ['my-snack-bar']
                });
```

my css:

```
    .my-snack-bar {
        background-color: #E8EAF6;
        color: #3D5AFE;
    }
```

How can I change the 'Ok' action button color?

Answer (score 22):

Version: "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",

You can access the colors with the panelClass option + the generated class ".mat-simple-snackbar-action".

My example:

*snackbar.component.ts*

```
  private configSuccess: MatSnackBarConfig = {
    panelClass: ['style-success'],    
  };

  private configError: MatSnackBarConfig = {
    panelClass: ['style-error'],
  };

  public snackbarSuccess(message) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, 'close', this.configSucces);
  }

  public snackbarError(message) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, 'close', this.configError);
  }
```

*snackbar.component.css*

```
  .style-success {
    color: $primary-text;
    background-color: $primary;
  }
  .style-success .mat-simple-snackbar-action  {
    color: $primary-text;
  }
  .style-error {
    color: $warn-text;
    background-color: $warn;
  }
  .style-error .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
    color: $warn-text;
  }
```

**Extra info** If using a mixin for custom themes you can do something like this to get all the colors:

```
@mixin snackbar($theme) {
  $primary: mat-color(map-get($theme, primary));
  $primary-text: mat-color(map-get($theme, primary), default-contrast);
  $warn: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn));
  $warn-text: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn), default-contrast);

  .style-success {
    color: $primary-text;
    background-color: $primary;
  }
  .style-success .mat-simple-snackbar-action  {
    color: $primary-text;
  }
  .style-error {
    color: $warn-text;
    background-color: $warn;
  }
  .style-error .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
    color: $warn-text;
  }
}
```

Comment: On Angular material ^11.0.4 i had to place css code into main style.css file. Placing it into component css file didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned above one can customise the style of the snack bar using the panelClass configurationn.

```
this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
            duration: 40000,
            panelClass: "success-dialog"
        });
```

The key here is to override via CSS the **mat-simple-snackbar-action**. This will do the trick of changing the action button text color.

```
.success-dialog {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: $success !important;
    .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
        color: white !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
.my-snack-bar button {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
.my-snack-bar {
    background-color: #E8EAF6;
}
```

css in your style.css(or .scss) file. It will not work if you put anywhere else.

Comment: upvote for pointing out the need of putting this into the rootstyles, which made it finally work for me.

Answer (score 6):

please add the following in app `style.css`

```
.mat-simple-snackbar { font-weight: 600; } // text     
.mat-simple-snackbar-action > button { color: red } // action
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

For me, below code is worked.

```
::ng-deep snack-bar-container simple-snack-bar .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steig's answer is correct but if that doesn't work then you should add `/deep/` in front of your class:

```
/deep/ .my-snack-bar button {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
let mysnackbar: any = document.querySelectorAll('.my-snack-bar')[0];
    mysnackbar.style.cssText += "color: #3D5AFE;backgroundColor: #E8EAF6";
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way to do this is to override the color variable for your `panelClass`, in `style.scss`:

```
.my-snackbar-panel-class {
  --mat-snack-bar-button-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create reusable method in your service file

```
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

constructor(
    private readonly snackBar: MatSnackBar
) { }

openSnackBar(
    message: string,
    action: string,
    className = '',
    duration = 1000) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
        duration: duration,
        panelClass: [className]
    });
}
```

**Call below method from your component**

```
this._dialog.openSnackBar(`Please contact IT team.`, "Okay", 'background-red');
```

**Add your class in your Style.scss**

```
.background-red {
    background: red;
}

.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
    --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: red !important;
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: red !important;
    --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
}

.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container .mat-mdc-button.mat-mdc-snack-bar-action:not(:disabled) {
    color: white;
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Output:

[image]